# jquery ajax call in ie8/9 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I feel like I should be able to find this anwser but have had zero success after hours of research.   I have this [page](http://static.athletesinaction.org/misc/test2.html) with a simple jquery ajax calls to a API service.   It works fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, and even IE 10.  But IE 9 and 8 seem to fail.

Here's the code:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://api.domain.org/api/campus?filtertype=name&filter="+ escape($('#campus').val()),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#results').children().remove();
                        var arrayd = (typeof result) == 'string' ? eval('(' + result + ')') : result;
                        if (arrayd != null) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < arrayd.length; i++) {
                                $('#results').append('<li>' + arrayd[i].SchoolName + '</li>');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
                        alert("There was an issue with the request");
                    } // When Service call fails
                });
```

The biggest issue is that the alert files, but I can't see any traffic in the IE Debugging tools which doesn't help me see if I even hit the server.

I've tried a number of things:

1. Setting $.ajax setting per http://mvcdiary.com/2013/01/16/jquery-ajax-request-not-working-in-ie9/
2. Setting '$.support.cors = true;' before the ajax call
3. Using 'jquery.iecors.js'

**Update**

After changing the dataType to 'jsonp' I started seeing the traffic in IE 8/9 with successful calls.   However, I'm not getting any browser to call the success method now.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://api.athletesinaction.org/api/campus?filtertype=name&filter="+ escape($('#campus').val()),
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/javascript",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    jsonpCallback: 'myTest',
                    success: myTest,
                    error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    } // When Service call fails
                });


        function myTest (argument) {
            alert("YEAH");
            $('#results').children().remove();
            var arrayd = (typeof result) == 'string' ? eval('(' + result + ')') : result;
            if (arrayd != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayd.length; i++) {
                    $('#results').append('<li>' + arrayd[i].SchoolName + '</li>');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing the JSON? What happens if you use `JSON.parse()` instead? What does the JSON response look like? What console errors are you getting in IE?

Comment: You should be using the [data] property on the ajax call to specify query parameters. Also, try jsonp.

Comment: IE8 and IE9 do not support XHR2, meaning to send a CORS request you must use a different XHR. jQuery doesn't provide that support, therefore you'll have to do it yourself or install a plugin that does it for you. setting cors support to true is absolutely useless, there's never a case in a desktop browser where you'll want to do that.

Comment: OP shouldn't need JSONP or CORS since the request is being sent to the same domain. Though it's a different sub-domain, so `document.domain = "athletesinaction.org";` may be needed.

Comment: It is a cross-origin request, therefore CORS/jsonp is needed unless you can get around it with document.domain.

Comment: All- thanks for the help.   I tried changing the dataType to 'jsonp' and I believe I am getting further in IE.   Will try using JSON.parse() tomorrow when I get back to work.  Will report my results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `dataType` to `jsonp`.

Though the service will need to support this type of request.

Comment: I changed my datatype and I get a response, but now throws an error in Chrome, so I likely need to parse it different in the success function now.

Comment: I haven't determined if I have an issue with my JSON or what, but have been unable to parse.   I did determine that I was seeing roughly 1.44% of the traffic to that page using ie8 or 9, so it's not something I could send many more hours working with.  I believe I am serving most of my users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not works in IE8.

If you need to support IE8, take JSONP or postMessage, or combination of both.